# Ruby HAML doesn't respect booleans?

Tags: ruby, haml

I have a loop in HAML as follows:

```
- first = true
- @years.each do |year|
  %th #{year}
  - first = false and next if first == true
  %th #{year} &Delta;
  %th #{year} &Delta; %
```

The goal is to add `delta` columns for years following the first year.

Debugging the row I can see that `first` is correctly being set to `false`, however the columns following the `next` are still being outputted.

If I perform the comparison without booleans, things work as expected:

```
- first = :true
- @years.each do |year|
  %th #{year}
  - first = :false and next if first == :true
  %th #{year} &Delta;
  %th #{year} &Delta; %
```

Does anyone understand what's going on under the hood?

Using `Ruby 2.2.3` and `HAML 4.0.7`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby, like many languages, has something called short-circuiting in boolean logic. Expressions like 'and' are only true if both expressions are true, so if the first expression is false, the second is never called.

In your case, `(first = false)` resolves to false, so the `and` expression returns false without ever running `next`.

This is an important feature for expressions like:

```
do.something if !myobject.nil? and myobject.some_method
```

Without short-circuiting, myobject.some_method would throw an error every time myobject was nil.

You can avoid the problem by writing your haml this way:

```
- first = true
- @years.each do |year|
  %th #{year}
  - if first == true
    - first = false
    - next
  %th #{year} &Delta;
  %th #{year} &Delta; %
```

Comment: Bah, total brain fart on my part, thanks, eiko. I was able to come up with a short one-liner, using utilities from the `finishing_moves` gem: `(first = false).false? and next if first.true?`